# C# 2 DateTime are not equal

Tags: c#, datetime

I have one strange problem that I'm trying to understand. 
In my controller there are 2 DateTime objects that I want to compare.

You can see screenshot from a debugger in my controller. I create one date time and get another one from a model. 
At this step you can see in debugger that date1 differs from date2 for 2 seconds
[image: debuger - step 1]

At the next step I remove 2 seconds from date2 and compare it with date1

[image: debugger 2]

Cay you explain me why is it false? In debugger I see both of them the same.

[image]

**Solution:** As it was told in the comment, the idea was to check also milliseconds, I completely forgot about it!

Comment: Check the milliseconds

Comment: How about comparing both dates' tick values?

Comment: Well, you see that they're the same as far as the seconds. We don't know the *exact* value of `model.Available.MinDate`. It might actually be 2016-07-18T18:45:00.001 or something like that.

Comment: You could subtract one from the other and compare the absolute value of the difference to some tolerance if that's what you're really looking to do.

Comment: Try adding Watches for `date1.ToString("o")` and `date2.ToString("o")`. This will reveal all digits present. Also a suffix depending on the `DateTimeKind` might be seen, but that is not considered when comparing using `date1 == date2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,472), a comparison of two DateTime objects is done through their respective ticks, which is their internal representation.

Comparing two DateTime values is a bit like comparing two floating point values: the difference might be so small that you're likely to not get what you want. Perhaps you need to check if they're on the same date, or if one falls in a specific range of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.Compare to see which time is earlier/later. Also like people have already mentioned difference could be in e.g. milliseconds

How to use DateTime.Compare:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's fine to reference existing answers, but it would be more helpful if you provided some additional pointers on how people might use your suggestion for this problem or similar ones. `DateTime.Compare` by itself is not really an answer to the question. For instance, *how* to tell from the output of `DateTime.Compare` which is earlier/later?

Answer (score 0):

The way to compare Datetimes is done by comparing their Tick property:

```
bool r = date1.Ticks == date2.Ticks;
```

Try this.